# Entra ID issuing expired ID Tokens

Tags: sso, azure, oidc

We are integrating our application with SSO using Entra ID App Registrations and configuring OIDC.

When our application receives the ID token from Microsoft Entra, the `iap` and `exp` values seem invalid.  This has been occurring for a few months now consistently, ever since we first started to integrate with Entra ID.

The problem is that the `iat` claim is dated five minutes in the past, and the `exp` claim is actually the time that I believe should be placed in the `iat`.

Consequently, when the OIDC authentication module examines the token we end up rejecting it because it is already expired.  I don't have this issue with other OIDC providers -- they seem to set `iat` and `exp` as expected.

If I am unable to find a solution for this problem I will have to add an additional "fudge factor" on top of the provided `exp` so that our application can function against Microsoft Entra.

```
  "iat": 1702682589 <-- always exactly 5 minutes in the past
  "nbf": 1702682589
  "exp": 1702682889 <-- always "right now"
```

Am I misunderstanding something?  Any clarification is much appreciated -- thank you!

Comment: Adjust your [clock skew factor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/configurable-token-lifetimes).

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing seems to alleviate this concern.  Even adding 8 hours to the lifetime using Microsoft Graph has no impact on the exp: claim, and the token continues to be expired the moment it is issued.  I am adding code to detect if Microsoft Entra is the IdP and adding 5 minutes to the expiration as this will satisfy our usage need.

Comment: Check out settings of Azure Idp where expiry time of tokens is configured. There you will find clock skew factor. OIDC libs also allow you to adjust skew in your own code. You are using default 5 min expiry time. It tells me that you haven't configured your OIDC client yet.